# Preventing click event in div that is inside of li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've been searching for a while for answer but nothing really helped me in my problem.
I have div inside and li element (to position in at the bottom of that li element).
I've made some functions to show and hide that div when user clicks on that li element, but I want to stop hiding it when it is clicked (not a li element).

Here are my functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#panel-user-item").click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleUserPanel();
    });

    /*$(document).mouseup(function(e)
    {
        var subject = $("#panel-user-panel"); 

        if(e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && !subject.has(e.target).length)
        {
            subject.hide(300);
            subject.addClass("hide");
        }
    });*/

});

function toggleUserPanel()
{
    if(!$("#panel-user-panel").hasClass("hide"))
    {
        $("#panel-user-panel").hide(300);
        $("#panel-user-panel").addClass("hide");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#panel-user-panel").show(300);
        $("#panel-user-panel").removeClass("hide");     
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that? I'v been searching for few hours already and didn't find any good solutions. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[**`event.stopPrapagation()`**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, but will it stop clickig also any element inside that div? (for example: link to user options, or some kind of text area to send quick status of user)??

I'll check that, but I think that it's not bad idea o just ask ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
e.stopPropagation()
```